# Pandas. Mergins with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DFs.

df1 is smth like:

```
pins     date       transaction
UANS12   01.02.03   560
UANS12   03.04.03   976
UJJJS9   03.02.04   876
```

df2 is smth like:

```
pins     registration_ date 
UANS12   01.02.03
UJJJS9   09.01.01
```

I need to compare pins in df1 with registration date in df2. And add a new column in df1 with regdate.
I tried to use:

```
new = pd.merge(df1, df2[["registration_date"]], on="pins", how="right")
```

but got error :

```
   # Check for duplicates
   KeyError: 'pins'
```

Comment: "I need to compare pins in df1 with registration date in df2. And add a new column in df1 with regdate." I am not entirely sure what you mean. Do you want to add a column `registration_date` to df1, based on the matches between `df1['pins']` and `df2['pins']`. Should anything happen to the duplicates? Or should each row with `UANS12` simply get `01.02.03` in the new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `merge()` on `how='left'`

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='pins', how='left')
###
     pins      date  transaction registration_date
0  UANS12  01.02.03          560          01.02.03
1  UANS12  03.04.03          976          01.02.03
2  UJJJS9  03.02.04          876          09.01.01
```

or by `join()`

```
df1['registration_date'] = df1.set_index('pins').join(df2.set_index('pins'), on='pins', how='left')['registration_date'].values
###
     pins      date  transaction registration_date
0  UANS12  01.02.03          560          01.02.03
1  UANS12  03.04.03          976          01.02.03
2  UJJJS9  03.02.04          876          09.01.01
```

or by `map()`

```
df1['registration_date'] = df1['pins'].map(dict(zip(df2['pins'], df2['registration_date'])))
df1
###
     pins      date  transaction registration_date
0  UANS12  01.02.03          560          01.02.03
1  UANS12  03.04.03          976          01.02.03
2  UJJJS9  03.02.04          876          09.01.01
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you re trying to merge df1 with a dataframe that not contains 'pins' columns
when you use df2[["registration_date"]] you create a dataframe with a single column instead you need to use df2